# How to decrypt substitution cipher with keys with multiple letters?

Tags: python, cryptography

I have found the following encoded message [here](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/pitch-haven-hub), it is obviously in hexadecimal and each two digit sequence corresponds to a byte, decoding the byte sequence gives the following message:

```
"UAYUYAF FOY YIÆZYUA'W KYWLAJL. \r\nYUAÆWY YIÆL FI' SUAYY YIÆLZLALK. \r\nOYUAÆIRK FOY LYIO ÆJY. \r\nÆLLLAOLAIRÆFY LYYK, VGUAWGY IOÆLF. \r\nUAYPHYIR LAL FOY KYWFUAGAFLAI'L I'S OLAW LAYIÆJY. \r\nPGFAOYUA FOY YIÆZYUA. KYPHI'GUA OLAW AÆUAAÆWW. \r\nUAYAIRÆLAYI IOOÆF IOÆW FÆZYL."
```

In multiple lines:

```
UAYUYAF FOY YIÆZYUA'W KYWLAJL.
YUAÆWY YIÆL FI' SUAYY YIÆLZLALK.
OYUAÆIRK FOY LYIO ÆJY.
ÆLLLAOLAIRÆFY LYYK, VGUAWGY IOÆLF.
UAYPHYIR LAL FOY KYWFUAGAFLAI'L I'S OLAW LAYIÆJY.
PGFAOYUA FOY YIÆZYUA. KYPHI'GUA OLAW AÆUAAÆWW.
UAYAIRÆLAYI IOOÆF IOÆW FÆZYL.
```

I was able to find the substitution cipher used by the message:

```
cipher = {
    "A": "C",
    "DE'": "X",
    "F": "T",
    "G": "U",
    "I'": "O",
    "IL": "Y",
    "IO": "W",
    "IR": "L",
    "J": "G",
    "K": "D",
    "KH": "Q",
    "L": "N",
    "LA": "I",
    "O": "H",
    "P": "B",
    "PH": "V",
    "S": "F",
    "U": "J",
    "UA": "R",
    "V": "P",
    "W": "S",
    "XU": "Z",
    "Y": "E",
    "YI": "M",
    "Z": "K",
    "Æ": "A",
}
```

As you can see, the cipher contains keys with two letters, some of which has parts that are also keys, and I have confirmed if a digram is in the cipher, it may or may not have been used, in other words its parts may have been used individually and each replaces a letter, or the digram as a whole replaces one letter, it is deliberately ambiguous:

```
import re

regex = "(" + "|".join(sorted(cipher, key=lambda x: -len(x))) + ")"

print("".join(s if (s := cipher.get(i)) else i for i in re.split(regex, message)))
```

```
REJECT THE MAKER'S DESIGN.
ERASE MAN TO FREE MANKIND.
HERALD THE NMH AGE.
ANNIHILATE NEED, PURSUE WANT.
REVMR IN THE DESTRUCTION OF HIS IMAGE.
BUTCHER THE MAKER. DEVOUR HIS CARCASS.
RECLAIM WHAT WAS TAKEN.
```

Overall the translation seems legit, but there are two errors, `NMH` should be `NEW` and `REVMR` should be `REVEL`.

I wonder how to solve the general case, given an encoded string encoded using a substitution cipher that contains ngrams, some parts of the ngrams are also used to substitute plain text, find all possible ways to break the string into permutations of the keys, so that each character in the original encoded message is left as is if it isn't contained in any cipher keys, and continuous chunks of coding characters are split into parts in all possible ways that every part is a key in the cipher and no coding character is left behind.

I can't describe it in English well, basically I want all possible interpretations of the encoded message, the input is the string and the cipher dictionary, the output is a list of lists, each sublist contains parts from the secret message, the parts are strings and satisfy the following criteria: every part has no common character with any key in the cipher dictionary, or the part is contained in the cipher dictionary.

It is related to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76737259/16383578https://stackoverflow.com/a/76737259/16383578):

```
from collections import Counter


def substring_tree(s: str) -> dict:
    d = {}

    def worker(s: str, dic: dict):
        for i in range(1, len(s) + 1):
            dic[s[:i]] = {}
            worker(s[i:], dic[s[:i]])

    worker(s, d)
    return d


def traverse_tree(tree, wordbank, keys, substrings=list()):
    result = []
    for k, v in tree.items():
        if k in wordbank and keys[k] < wordbank[k]:
            keys = keys.copy()
            keys[k] += 1
            if v:
                result.extend(traverse_tree(v, wordbank, keys, substrings + [k]))
            else:
                result.append(substrings + [k])
    return result


def all_construct2(target, wordbank):
    wordbank = Counter(wordbank)
    return traverse_tree(substring_tree(target), wordbank, Counter())
```

Theoretically my code can work, if given arbitrarily large amount of time and RAM, when I tested the code the interpreter quickly eats multiple Gibibytes of RAM and I was forced to terminate it.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: The mis-translation seems related to `LYIO` having multiple potential translations. `L-YI-O` --> `NMH` and `L-Y-IO` --> `NEW`

Comment: `UAYPHYIR` to `REVEL` is a litter easier as though there exists an ambiguity translating `YI` to `M` or `Y` to `E` We can rule out the first case as `R` does not have a translation making `YI-R` an invalid interpretation of `YIR` leaving us with the proper interpretation `Y-IR` being `EL`

Comment: My intuition tells me there might be some rule/trick to disambiguation between working translations. Maybe taking the reverse of the message and keys to do the lookup. That aside, perhaps in cases where there were words with multiple working translations you could for their existence in a dictionary.